# Spring Boot Security and Keycloak - receive 403 forbidden /sso/login after successfull login when using HTTPS

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak, aws-application-load-balancer

I have a Spring Boot App using Spring Security and Keycloak as IDP.

Keycloak is available under https://auth.example.com, having a realm backo with a client backo-core and a testuser configured with the required roles.

If I configure my local app, using

```
keycloak.enabled=true
keycloak.auth-server-url=https://auth.example.com/auth
keycloak.realm=backo
keycloak.public-client=true
keycloak.resource=backo-core
keycloak.ssl-required=external
keycloak.confidential-port=443
```

Everything works fine.

If I deploy it to my DEV environment under https://backo.example.com/backo with https://backo.example.com/sso/login, when accessing the app I get redirect to the Keycloak login. After successful login I get redirected to the redirect URL with the state, session-state and code parameters but receive 403.
https://backo.example.com/sso/login?state=...&session_state=...&code=...
with request initiator chain coming from https://auth.example.com/auth/realms/backo/login-action/authenticate?...

If I set locally keycloak.ssl-required=all, the redirect_url parameter when accessing the login page is https://localhost/sso/login, so I can change it manually to http://localhost:8080/sso/login. After a successful login I have the exact same problem with a 403 Forbidden response for
http://localhost:8080/sso/login?state=...&session_state=...&code=...

with request initiator chain coming from https://auth.example.com/auth/realms/backo/login-action/authenticate?...

This is how my security config looks like

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            super.configure(http);
            http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/backo").hasAnyRole(ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_BACKOFFICE)
                .anyRequest().permitAll();

            http.csrf().disable();
            http.headers().frameOptions().disable(); // otherwise Vaadin doesn't work properly

            http
                .logout()
                .addLogoutHandler(keycloakLogoutHandler())
                .logoutUrl("/sso/logout").permitAll()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/");
        }
```

You can ignore this Vaadin workaround, as it fails in /sso/login already.
http.csrf().disable(); is required to prevent other 403 Forbidden errors on post request while authorization.

One thing that could be worth mentioning:
The Spring Boot App has no HTTPS enabled, in our dev environment it sits behind an AWS Application loadbalancer ALB. HTTPS is terminated in the ALB.

Answer (score 2):

We have faced the similar problem three days ago with spring boot thymeleaf application. We have used keycloak adapter (13.0.1) for spring boot.

After successful login  it was redirecting to /sso/login page with 403 error.

After lots of effort we finally got the configuration required to fix this issue. you need to use the below application properties :

```
server.use-forward-headers=true
keycloak.public-client=true
keycloak.ssl-required=all
keycloak.confidential-port=443
```